# Download Java 32 bit for mac os x

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome, osx-mavericks

I need to download the 32 bit Java so I can run Java applications in my chrome browser, but I can't find it anywhere. In the website below there's only the 64 bit version:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is your mac that old? What does your OS say? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201948
Why do you need 32 bit? 64 bit can run 32 bit emulation

Comment: That's not the problem. Please take a look in the thread below:

http://superuser.com/questions/231940/java-plugin-doesnt-work-in-chrome-how-can-i-fix-this

Seems that in chrome I cannot run java applications if I don't have the 32 bit version of Java

Comment: that was in 2011 when chromes was 32 bit only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before digging into getting a 32 version of Java, check your reference, that's a 2011 answer.

Furthermore if you check the java.com site:
 http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp

You will notice that chrome no longer support the plugin ( starting in april 2015 )

There's a way to enable it https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033

But I would suggest that you look for Google Chrome support on their support site:

https://support.google.com/chrome/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I received a comment in the forum you suggested me, saying that I can no longer open Java applications in chrome, so I'm accepting your answer as the correct answer. Below there's a link containing the thread I created in the forum.

http://tinyurl.com/ofu8oxc

Answer (score 0):

You can only get older versions at this site:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=es_LA&viewlocale=en_US

If this does not solve your problem you will have to switch to a 64-bit version of your browser.

Comment: Didn't work, and my browser is already 64-bit. This is a screenshot of the "about chrome" page

http://postimg.org/image/sxicygcsp/